# Issues with webpack.config

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, webpack, web-deployment

[I created a small project using scrimba.com](https://scrimba.com/c/cZPQ4Gc4). It works fine on scrimba's browser, but when I downloaded it and tried to open it on Chrome it doesn't work (or Firefox or GitHub Pages).

The error goes as follows: `.../script.pack.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`, so I figured it has to do with my script `src="script.pack.js"`, but can't make it work nor did I found a solution. I am new to coding and would appreciate a hand. Below are screenshots of the following files:

- [`index.html`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PNIy.png)
- [`package.json`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkAld.png)
- [`webpack.conf.js`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dz7nc.png)

Comment: Actually post some of your relevant reproducible code

Comment: Has something to do with the file path

Comment: Did you review Scrimba's `README.md` file? It should be inside the downloaded project files. You have to run `npm install` and then you can open `index.html` to view the final result.

Comment: That was it, thanks a lot @Juan